# Dealing with Boss's/ Senior Staff's family

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, united-kingdom, offices

I have worked and interned at small & medium size firms, ranging from 7 staff members to 100.

I have noticed time and time again when family member's visit, eg for lunch, they seem to think they are in charge of everything and can boss you around. This is especially true of wives, and I say this as a woman myself.

I am a junior member of staff and have been asked by them to check/ top up their meter on the parking, watch their kids, pop to the shops for them to buy a particular juice, make them coffee etc (don't mind the making coffee  but believe the request should come from the staff member they are visiting). They also love engaging in small talk that is patronising and demoralising eg 'oh you have a law degree. oh bless. good for you'.

Also some of the team members children intern and they seem to think they rule the roost because their mummy/daddy are senior partners. I have had to clear up after them eg move chairs back to the original spot, clear their coffee cups, give them extra long lunch breaks, ignore the fact that they spend most of their time on social media etc.

Is this part & parcel of office life, or are there boundaries that should be put in place? IMO family members are not staff (and I include a family firm I worked for where extended family members who were visiting thought they were my boss), nor are they clients. I see them as 'guests' of the firm and should have realistic expectations of what level of authority they have in a firm they are visiting.

Any thoughts or experiences?In case you haven't gathered I have a bit of a problem with authority.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. My positions have varied from admin assistant to paralegal but generally speaking, they have been junior/ semi-senior positions.
I get paid a salary no more, no less and there is no clocking in or out of shifts. Hospitality is definitely not part of my job, but it seems to be! I'm not a seasoned employee in workplaces however it strikes me that many senior members seem to just add to my job description which ever duties come up and need to be taken care of - maybe this is a boundary setting exercise because it is very easy to get taken advantage of and it puts me in a difficult position of not knowing how to say no.

Comment: This question seems very location and manager dependent. But as a general rule, if someone gives you an order in the office and you don't know if you should follow it, tell the person "I'll check that with my boss" and then ask your boss what to do. Works with colleagues, clients and also family of staff.

Comment: @Erik: I am not quite sure if this would really work with staff family in my location. If the wife said "Make me coffee", I said "I'll check that with my boss" and I have to wait for the boss because he is in a meeting right now and afterwards I say "my wife asked me an hour ago to make some coffee", I would look rather stupid to wife, boss and collegues. In my locale, it would be better to say "yes" or "no" right away if the boss is not easily available and it was a small request.

Comment: @guest there's a bad time for everything, but if you do this once or twice, you'll probably learn (from your boss) exactly what is expected of you in terms of catering to family, and you'll also be able to explain it to said family. Since this seems to be an expectation problem, this might be the fix for it.

Comment: Maybe you should ask them the code for the project those actions should be billed to. Some companies are really strict about accounting to the minute, while other are much more flexible, and even on the first type, there will be some leeway. The point is, asking that question shows that they are asking you to use company time for their own benefit. _It may make sense for the company that you do that_, then perfect, that goes into the books and all is well. If they are overstepping, they will probably be happy to make themselves a coffee when you show them for freee where the machine is located

Comment: Is hospitality part of your job? You didn't exactly explain what are you doing in those firms, as not all interns are the same.

Comment: Orginial poster, would you mind starting your job? The answer is probably really different for desk workers than others. Also relevant is if you write down your time or not (most teachers eg don't write down time). Otherwise, people here will assume Software Industry.

Comment: @guest What do you mean, time?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: I used to work in Software Industry, I wrote down the time I worked and was paid exactly for that time (the first 38,5 hours a week the normal rate and then overtime pay). Now I work in Academia and I don't write down my time. So my "company" has no problem if I work more minutes because someone asks me an additional question (or wants me to make coffee) as they don't have to pay me more.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, but if you feel that visitors or colleagues are being impertinent with their requests, you can make it clear that those are not your responsibilities at the workplace, or that the employment relationship may be at stake over the disrespectful and unbusinesslike nature of their conduct. If you are employed as a domestic servant or tea lady or otherwise formally recognised in the capacity of errand runner for visitors, then that would be fine, but that is unlikely here. We all recognise the difference between cooperating for a business purpose, and conduct designed to demean.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, I got the impression the OP was staff, not an intern. She referred to having interned by way of her background and experience with this issue. I would admit to having a problem with authority myself, like most people, if we are talking about this style of crony authority. I think it's less common for men to encounter or engage in this sort of behaviour however, because many male victims would swing a punch at the aggressor, or at the very least the male aggressor would fear from experience some sort of confrontation and embarrassment (even if it was only sharply being told "no")

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's completely understandable if these situations are frustrating. You don't have to have a problem with authority for that to be the case.

But I think the take away from all this is that there are workplaces where spouses will act with some authority, and their partners will allow it. Provided that your manager is aware, there isn't really much you can do, especially if such duties would generally fall under your responsibility.

You need to ask your manager how they would like you to act in such situations. If you've been mildly inconvenienced, maybe the best thing you can do is grin and bear it.

Comment: I would emphasize the point in the last paragraph. Unless delegated to you, prioritization is your boss's problem. Something like "Hey boss, your kids were in and your spouse asked for help with them. They're great! But I was with them for 4 hours which prevented me from getting x done. Do you want me to check in with you next time, or just take care of them when asked?

Answer (score 3):

You have three separate categories of family members here, and there is not one rule for all of them.

First, when a spouse of an owner or a very senior member of staff visits, they are an Honoured Guest. You make them coffee if they ask. If you're going to get coffee for yourself, you ask if you can bring them one at the same time. You're delighted to see them and you want to make their visit pleasant. If they ask you to leave the premises (even just to go outside and put money in the meter) you do it with a smile, but the next time you see their spouse after the guest has left, you check that it was ok for you to do that. If it's not, you can ask how to handle a request like that next time - deferring to someone else on the team, for example. Same if you have to stop your regular work to entertain a child or something else you wouldn't normally do.

Second, employees who are related to other employees should be treated exactly like any other employee, with one exception: if you think their work ethic isn't what it should be, don't try to correct it yourself. If you just see that they are on social media during work hours but it doesn't affect your work, do and say nothing. If your work is delayed because they didn't do something on time, mention only that (and not the reason they weren't on time) to your manager as you would if it was not someone's child who let you down, but just another employee. If you are not the manager of the intern, don't manage them. They already have both a manager and a parent monitoring them at work. And yes, their parents may have decided to pay them as an intern even though they under-perform by objective standards. You pointing that out is not likely to result in anyone being happier than they were before.

[To expand on that: imagine you own a business and your child is messy and not hardworking. You want to fix that, so you give them a job they basically have to take, hoping they will become neater and harder working. They may even improve somewhat, though perhaps not to the level that would keep them employed by strangers. You continue to work on this, talking to them privately at home, for example. And then one day a complete junior tells them off, or comes to you demanding they be told off or fired, or is suddenly all concerned about the company's profits and how much is spent on intern salaries for nothing. If you could fix your kid in an instant you would have already. You're trying. And now this junior is calling you out for having a lazy messy kid. Are you likely to thank them for it?]

If you don't normally clear up after other staff members, you could mention to your manager that lately the meeting room has really been in a state and you've had to take time to deal with it. Again do this from the point of "should I have done that or should I have told you about it or asked someone else to do it?" not from the point of complaining about the mess-leavers. You'll get some direction about what to do next time, and of course you've also left that little nugget of information with your manager and there may be some action quietly taken.

The third category is family of non senior people (such as yourself) who are not employed by the company in any capacity. If they visit, they are just visiting their own family member. Be polite to them, but don't do things for them. The honoured guests are visiting the whole company and get hospitality from the whole company. Not every visitor is in that category.

Answer (score 2):

I find this quite surprising that location is tagged in the UK. I have worked in Asia and can imagine this to be more common there with large family owned businesses. I now work in the UK. However two things make this strange for the UK.

1. Many UK businesses are not family run:
   In any given sector, there will typically be plenty of work options that are not family run. So if family run companies are too weird, no one will work there.
2. Culturally, open displays of nepotism are generally frowned on:
   This runs counter to what people generally consider fair in the UK. Therefore I would expect employees to be upset and either kick up a fuss or leave.

Therefore, I would lean towards saying that this is strange and abnormal. I dont know your specific industry but this sounds very unprofessional. If I were in your situation I would research what similar employers in your industry are like and plan a move. It might make sense for you to grit your teeth and bear it for a few months until you are in a good position to move on. If management are bad enough to let this type of thing occur in the first place I would not have faith in them "fixing" the problem. You can try to change things but ultimately many people put family above everything including their own financial interests.

Comment: I think you're right in some sense, though you underestimate the number of family run / individual/ privately owned business as opposed to corporate owned.  Even in law many firms are partner owned thus the nepotism.

Comment: @Sally101 Law firms are probably the exception because it’s illegal for non-lawyers to own them.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bringing a spouse to work who makes you run errands:

Show the trade-off in productivity such errands cost.

It's unprofessional for the senior staff to let their family members do that. However rather than resisting, or talking to them or the spouses lately discretely, (both of which may be career limiting moves), I'd advise when you predict this situation has a chance of occurring (eg wife walks in), delve deep into something work related that looks like it can't wait (even if it probably can).

You want it to look like you're being forced to lower your productivity in order to tend to their requests. Your boss needs to stop you working in order to reassign you to run the errands.

If you need to call someone to discuss something long and complex and clearly work related, this is the time. Become too busy in your work to be distracted, or at least try to appear that way. Try to look as busy as possible, eat your lunch at your desk while complaining about all the work you need to do.

There's advice elsewhere on how to appear busier in an office environment (eg schedule emails to send later at night), use some of these after being used as a servant - you "worked later" because you were behind in your work.

#### Interns who are lazy cause dad owns the place

Offer to help work *with* them. Not "For", with.

After a meeting in which they hosted and should tidy the room, "That meeting went well, do you want some help tidying the room?"

See them on social media; "Would you like some help preparing for ... next thing ...?"

Worse case you're going to end up picking up the slack for them anyway, but most people who leave a meeting room messy cause its hard work to clean it up wont turn down an offer to help clean it together. Most people wont turn down an offer to improve their life in the future. By offering to help you also help clarify requirements and instruct - they may legitimately not know what to do next.

This also elevates you from "person who fixes things behind the scenes uncredited" to being thanked by them, and part of their story of their time there. If their senior partner hears how helpful and useful you are, this karma may come back around.